# Qual a melhor estratégia para fazer a sincronía de dados offline/online?

Tags: android

Estou pra conseguir pegar um aplicativo pra vendas externas, ele basicamente irá realizar pedidos e caso não possua conexão com a internet, ele irá sincronizar quando tiver. Bom..

Como deixar esse aplicativo profissional?

Exemplo: Utilização de services, broadcastReceivers, webservice, isto eu tenho em mente pra utilizar, alguém pode me ajudar oque um aplicativo tem q ter pra ser considerado bom, profissional?

Comment: Olá @brunoh. Bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Sua pergunta está muito amplas e as respostas provavelmente seriam baseadas em opniões, o que foge do modelo desta comunidade. Recomendo uma visita à [help] principalmente na seção [ask]. Você depois pode [edit]á-la para que os outros OP possam lhe ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Alguns pontos para considerar:

1. Para permitir operação offline (vendas externas) seu aplicativo deverá conter todos os produtos em uma base de dados local (exemplo: em [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html))
2. É preciso fazer a sincronia sempre que possível, dependendo da frequência de mudança destes produtos...se estes são atualizados mensalmente, então você pode usar um [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) para fazer esta atualização periódica, considerando casos, por exemplo, se o celular estiver desligado no momento do 'trigger', ao ligar o aparelho fazer a verificação e 'atualização' se houver conexão.
3. Você pode também partir de uma estratégia em que você só sincroniza quando o aparelho estiver conectado em Wifi, você pode verificar os tipos de conexão com o [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html)
4. Para fazer o downloads dos dados, você quem escolhe o formato, se for em um serviço JSON ou um lote de dados em zip. A escolha não vai deixar de ser menos ou mais profissional.
5. Acredito que precisará fazer o upload dos pedidos realizados enquanto estava offline, aí você certamente precisará de um webservice disponível no servidor para receber estes dados. A partir deste requisito, faz-se necessário um webserver rodando para receber estes dados e processá-los.

A utilização de [BroadcastReceivers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) fará-se necessário na detecção de mudança de tipo de conexão por exemplo, já o [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) fará-se necessário no momento de processamento das informações como 'download' dos dados do servidor e 'upload' dos dados para o servidor.

Comment: Para sincronização de dados, vale pesquisar sobre `SyncAdapter` e `ContentProvider`, sempre ouço falar neles quando o assunto é esse. Quanto ao aplicativo ser considerado bom/profissional, você deveria esclarecer na pergunta se se refere à experiência do usuário com o aplicativo (quando devem ser considerados pontos como UX, usabilidade, etc.) ou somente à escolha das tecnologias para desenvolvê-lo (exemplo: evitar o uso de _polling_, adotar a subclasse de `ViewGroup` mais adequada para cada tipo de layout de tela, etc).

Comment: Gostei muito da resposta Alécio Carvalho, não fugia da minha estratégia que estava em mente..

Comment: Sobre utilizar sysncAdapter, e uma interface que quando implementada em nossa class, você consegue usar o método doBackground? Que pra mim é como rodar em uma thread, devo estar errado, mais vi apenas uma vez e tenho esse pensamento dele, vou estudar mais sobre ele